# Invalid JSON from backend? Angular 7

Tags: json, angular, parsing

If you have invalid JSON coming back from the server to the front-end. Is there a way to automatically correct it in Angular? Or is it the servers job to send it correctly?

```
data: "{\"fiillingingo\": {\"refere\": null, \"secondary\": [], \"references\": [{\"referenc...}"
```

**ERROR AFTER TRYING JSON.parse()**

```
core.js:15723 ERROR SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 639`
```

For some reason when I copy and paste it from the backend response and set it to a variable manually its fine but when I set a variable directly from the http call is when I get the error

**Sercice.ts**

```
  export interface Response{
  x: string;
  y: number;
}
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class DraftService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getDraftData(ID: number):Observable<Response>{
    var url = `/services/****/drafts/${ID}/lob`;
    return this.http.get<Response>(url);
  }
}
```

**componnent.ts**

```
constructor(public data: DraftDocumentService) { }

  ngOnInit() {}

  loadClob(){
    this.data.getDraftData(this.ID).subscribe(response => {

      this.formatJSON =response.x;
      console.log(typeof this.formatJSON);

     },
      error =>{
        console.log('error');

      });
  }
```

Comment: Simple answer: the backend should send a correct json.

Comment: Honestly, as trite as Abdekarim's response sounds, it's _by far_ the best solution. Yes, you could regex parse the string response and "correct" it, pipe, tap and JSON.parse() yourself, but that comes along with a host of other problems...

Comment: For some reason when I copy and paste it from the backend response and set it to a variable manually its fine but when I set a variable directly from the http call is when I get the error

Comment: @Flash Ok, in that case, can  you provide your service code, any `HTTPInterceptors` you have hooked, and the _complete_ JSON payload you receive? The "Unexpected token `u`" often happens when trying to `JSON.parse()` a variable that's `undefined` (hence the `u` when stringified).

Comment: Thanks for updated the question. And inside the `.subscribe()` if you `console.dir(response)` what do you get? (You can add that into the question, too).

Comment: I think I answered a similar question yesterday. Maybe you can return something like this from your service.
```return JSON.parse(JSON.stringify((data.replace(/(&nbsp;|<([^>]+)>)/ig, "")))));```

Comment: Yeah I thought it was working but it only worked when I copied and pasted what was coming back not sure what is goin on?

Comment: @mansford its very long to post on here